# En unity ¿Como puedo aumentar una variable de tipo "int" una unica vez dentro de update?

Tags: c#, lista, bucle-for, unity, integer

Lo que quiero hacer es detectar cuantas fichas dentro de una list<> tienen un bool activado mediante el uso de un for loop pero almomento de hacerlo este sigue aumentando constantemente.

este es mi codigo:

```
int ObjetosActivado;

list<GameObjects> listaDeObjetos;

void update()
{

for(i = 0;i < listaDeObjetos.count; i++)
   {
     if(listaDeObjetos[i].GetComponent<Objeto>().boolActivado == true)
         {
           objetosActivados++;
         } 
   }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir una sola vez? solamente sumar uno si uno de los objetos cumple? o en que momento?

Comment: Se me hace raro que no tengas un error de variable sin inicializar. Supongo que la defines en el editor. Por otro lado quería mencionar que los ifs actúan de acuerdo a un valor booleano, es decir, si es verdadero, proceden a ejecutar el código en su interior. Tú con la comparación `==` recibes un booleano. Entonces `if (booleano == true)` es lo mismo que decir simplemente `if (booleano)`. El equivalente a `booleano == false` es negarlo, así `!booleano`.

Comment: `cuentaObjetosActivados = 0` antes del `for` , `cuentaObjetosActivados++` dentro del `for` y `objetosActivados = cuentaObjetosActivados` luego del `for`

Comment: Es para que todos lo entiendan evidentemente, ademas de que tu solución solo sirve para detectar un objeto y no mas.

Answer (score 0):

@ALEMAN PLAY yo le pondria otro if fuera del bucle para que no te entrara si se ha aumentado la variable.
Para un solo objeto:
int ObjetosActivado = 0;

```
list<GameObjects> listaDeObjetos;

void update()
{
  if(objetosActivados == 0){
    for(i = 0;i < listaDeObjetos.count; i++)
    {
      if(listaDeObjetos[i].GetComponent<Objeto>().boolActivado)
      {
          objetosActivados++;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

De esta manera se inicia la variable a 0 se repatea el bucle si boolactivado es true entrara en la condicion y te aumentara la variable objetosActivados. Pero no volvera a entrar en el bucle porque ya tiene valor por lo tanto siempre la tendras a 1 cuando quieras la vuelves a poner a 0 para que te vuelva a entrar.

Para varios Objetos:

```
List<GameObjects> listaDeObjetosActivados = new List<GameObjects>();
list<GameObjects> listaDeObjetos;

void update()
{
  if(objetosActivados == 0){
    for(i = 0;i < listaDeObjetos.count; i++)
    {
      if(listaDeObjetos[i].GetComponent<Objeto>().boolActivado)
      {
          listaDeObjetosActivados.Add(listaDeObjetos[i]);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

De esta manera te creas una lista vacía y en el bucle vas detectando los objetos que tienen boolActivado a true si es true lo agregas a la lista nueva. El resultado sera una lista nueva con todos los objetos que están Activados.

Comment: la solución que me diste si funciona pero solo con un objeto. Pero creo que la solucion mas factible seria crear una lista local que añada los objetos detectados y hacer que la variable "Int" sea igual a "List.count" .

Comment: @ALEMANPLAY He modificado la respuestas para realizarlo con un item o para que el resultado sea una lista de objetos activados. Espero que te sirva la explicación de esta manera.